# Get current range of a spinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

My question is quite simple, unfortunately I can't find an answer.
Basically, I have a Swing window, with 2 `JSpinner`s. The second `JSpinner` has to define the high bound of the first `JSpinner`. So for example, if the user puts the value 4 on the second `JSpinner`, they mustn't be able to put a value higher than 4 in the first `JSpinner`. And if the value currently displayed in the first `JSpinner` is higher than 4 I'll set it to 4.

So I've built my two `JSpinner`s with `SpinnerNumberModel` in the constructor to set the initial bounds:

```
// First spinner
SpinnerNumberModel spinnerLimits_sante = new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 0.25, 3, 0.25);
JSpinner spin_sante = new JSpinner(spinnerLimits_sante);

// Second spinner
JSpinner spin_sante_max = new JSpinner(spinnerLimits_sante_max);
SpinnerNumberModel spinnerLimits_sante_max = new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 3, 32767, 1);
```

To get the value of the second `JSpinner` when it changes, I thought about using a `ChangeListener` on it. So each time it changes, I can get the new value, recreate a `SpinnerNumberModel` object using the new bounds (the low-bound and the interval wouldn't change, however the high-bound will be updated and the value will be updated if it is higher than the high-bound).

```
ChangeListener listenerSanteMax = new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        int newBound = spin_sante_max.getValue();
        // ...
    }
};
spin_sante_max.addChangeListener(listenerSanteMax);
```

Unfortunately this is where I'm stuck: `JSpinner` has no getter that would return a `SpinnerNumberModel` object nor its values.
And even if there was one, it seems there's no setter either.

So, my question:
*Is it possible to dynamically change the range and value of a spinner?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the model from the `Spinner` (test if it's an `instanceof` `SpinnerNumberModel`) and use it. *"So, my question: Is it possible to dynamically change the range and value of a spinner?"* - I've not tried, but once you have the `SpinnerNumberModel`, you can change it's properties

Comment: Are you familiar with something called type-casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ChangeListener`, instead of creating a new [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#setMaximum-java.lang.Comparable-), just *update* the maximum value of the existing model. Here's two ways to do it.

If the `ChangeListener` *can* see the spinner models, you can do the update directly.

```
ChangeListener listenerSanteMax = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        Number newMaximum = spinnerLimits_sante_max.getNumber().doubleValue();
        spinnerLimits_sante.setMaximum((Comparable) newMaximum);
    }
};
```

If the `ChangeListener` *can't* see the spinner models, you can do a [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).
 [`JSpinner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) has a `getModel()` method the returns a `SpinnerModel`. You can cast it to a `SpinnerNumberModel`, but you should use `instanceof` to check that the cast will work.

```
ChangeListener listenerSanteMax = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JSpinner) {
            JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner) source;
            SpinnerModel sm = spinner.getModel();
            if (sm instanceof SpinnerNumberModel) {
                SpinnerNumberModel model = (SpinnerNumberModel) sm;
                Number newMaximum = model.getNumber().doubleValue();
                spinnerLimits_sante.setMaximum((Comparable) newMaximum);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In either case, `newMaximum` is a [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html?is-external=true), and all subclasses supported by `SpinnerNumberModel` are `Comparable`.

Comment: I didn't even realize you could use the `SpinnerNumberModel` after having "put" it into the spinner. My listener can see the spinners so I've used the first solution, and added a small verification to update the value of my first spinner (through its `SpinnerNumberModel`) if it is higher than the value of the second spinner. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Use `getMode()` to obtain the model from the `JSpinner` and type-cast it to `SpinnerModelNumber` like this:

```
SpinnerNumberModel snm = (SpinnerNumberModel)spinner.getModel();
```